# Spring interface injection from external jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have spring API based authentication classes in external library,

Below are some of the classes in external library,

```
package com.security;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
@Component
public class ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider.class);

  private ApiAuthCredentialsConfig apiAuthCredentialsConfig;

  public ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider(ApiAuthCredentialsConfig apiAuthCredentialsConfig) {
    this.apiAuthCredentialsConfig = apiAuthCredentialsConfig;
  }
}
```

ApiAuthCredentialsConfig:

```
package com.security;
public interface ApiAuthCredentialsConfig {
    String getAuthToken();

    String getAuthTokenHeaderName();
}
```

And in the repo I have added the above external library as a gradle dependency.

I have below changes in actual repo.

```
@Component
@Data
public class ApiAuthenticationConfig implements ApiAuthCredentialsConfig {
    @Value("${auth-token}")
    private String authToken;
    @Value("${auth-token-header-name}")
    private String authTokenHeaderName;
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider apiKeyAuthenticationProvider;

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
httpSecurity.
antMatcher("/**").
csrf().disable().
sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).
and().addFilterBefore(new ApiKeyAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), apiKeyAuthenticationProvider.getHeaderName()), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(apiKeyAuthenticationProvider));
}
}
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.security"})
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

When I run the application its failing with below error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.security.ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider required a bean of type 'com.security.ApiAuthCredentialsConfig' that could not be found.
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the package of `ApiAuthenticationConfig`? Your application is only scanning components under _com.security_

Comment: Good catch @DirkDeyne after moving ApiAuthenticationConfig to com.security package it started worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the above comment, I realized that `ApiAuthenticationConfig` is not in the same package as `ApiAuthCredentialsConfig`, after I moved `ApiAuthenticationConfig` to `com.security` package it started working.